# Kivy: self.minimum_height not working for widget inside ScrollView

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I recently started to get in to Kivy and now I am trying to create app for me and my friends which is a D&D sheet. I wanted to have all the important stats in one tab in which you can scroll down so that the text font doesn't have to be that small but I can't get it working with the `self.minimum_height` property of the GridLayout that will contain other elements.

I am running kivy version 1.10.0
If I set the height manually the ScrollView works just fine.

Here is my .kv file

```
<TabbedPanel>:
do_default_tab: False
tab_pos: 'bottom_mid'
tab_width: self.width / 4
TabbedPanelItem:
    text: "Character"
    ScrollView:
        size_hint: (1, None)
        height: root.height
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            Button:
                text: "Hello"
            Button:
                text: "Hello"
            Button:
                text: "Hello"
            Button:
                text: "Hello"
            Button:
                text: "Hello"
            Button:
                text: "Hello"
            Button:
                text: "Hello"
            Button:
                text: "Hello"
            Button:
                text: "Hello"
            Button:
                text: "Hello"
            Button:
                text: "Hello"
            Button:
                text: "Hello"
            Button:
                text: "Hello"
            Button:
                text: "Hello"
            Button:
                text: "Hello"

TabbedPanelItem:
    text: "Weap's & Mods"
TabbedPanelItem:
    text: "Vehicle"
TabbedPanelItem:
    text: "Vehicle Upgr"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also set an explicit height for each contained widget, so that the GridLayout can add them together to calculate its minimum height. For instance, in your example you could add the following lines to each button:

```
size_hint_y: None
height: dp(30)
```

Comment: Thanks! It finally works. Seems a bit weird. Isn't there another workaround or is this the default way the ScrollView is designed by developers?

Comment: This is by design. If you don't set heights for your Buttons, what do you expect the GridLayout'r minimum_height to be?

Comment: I'd expect it to be the sum of the default heights for the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Cant comment yet, so have to make a separate answer:
You could make:

```
<My_button>(Button):
    size_hint_y: None
    height: dp(30)
```

And use that in your Gridlayout. That would save repeating it for each entry.

Comment: This has to be out of the scope of the root element right? In this example it would be the `<TabbedPanel>`

Comment: Yes the definition of mybutton goes outside the definition of tabbedpannel

Answer (score 0):

The self.minimum_height did not work for me.
but I got a different solution which allowed me to scroll.

```
 height: self.parent.height
```

```
Menu:
<Menu>:

    ScrollView:
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: self.parent.height

        BoxLayout:
            orientation:'vertical'
            size_hint_y: 2

            Button: 
                text: "Widget 1"

            
            Button: 
                text: "Widget 2"

            Button: 
                text: "Widget 3"


            Button: 
                text: "Widget 4"
 
            Button: 
                text: "Widget 5"
```